# Changing the parent class of around 12 different classes using Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working with a Scrapy project at the moment, and all the spiders thus far extend from the base CrawlSpider class that comes with Scrapy.

That's changed, and now I've got a brand new custom written base class (lets call it BaseSpider) that all spiders have to extend.

Is there any quick way to do this? I tried project wide search and replace, but I ended up replacing the entire class declaration line, not just the parent. And the 'Refactor' context menu didn't seem to have anything I could use either.